# Trigger a modal without a button click in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple modal that is triggered on a condition that displays a message like..

html:

```
<div ng-if="getGuestModal()"></div>
```

controller:

```
  $scope.guestIndicator = function () {
    return true;
  };

  $scope.guestModal = function() {
        $modal.open({
          animation: true,
          controller: guestModalController
          templateUrl: "./guestModal.html"
        });
    };

  $scope.getGuestModal = function () {
    if ($scope.guestIndicator()) {
      $scope.guestModal ();
    }
  };
```

running into an error that says "Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

any ideas?

Comment: can you create a plnkr

Comment: What kind of trigger are you looking for? You could have it popup automatically with something like `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I want it to trigger when my ng-if="getGuestModa()" is true...so where should i put the setTimeout() in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps just reducing some of the code complexity will fix this...

```
<div ng-if="getGuestModal()"></div>
```

In the div you have a function that will run on page load. The function returns **undefined**, which is **falsy**, so **ng-if** value will be **"false"**; never true.

If you want your function *getGuestModal* to fire on page load as it is with the ng-if, then perhaps in your controller you could just do this...

```
// Controller...

if(guestIndicator()){
  $scope.guestModal();
}
```

I'm guessing your *div* is **NOT** your actual **HTML** for the modal, just your hook to activate the function to fire your logic.

Another way you could do this is just connect your **MODAL** in the view with it's own custom directive, something like

```
<my-modal ng-if="isGuest"></my-modal>
```

and then in your controller something on load like this...

```
// Controller...

$scope.isGuest = myLogicFunctionThatReturnsABoolean();
```

> In your custom directive...

```
app.directive("myModal",...

  return {
    restrict: "E",
    boiler plate....
    controller: function($scope){
      $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        controller: guestModalController
        templateUrl: "./guestModal.html"
      });
    }
  }
```

> Another thing to mention...

A modal is typically in the rendered dom even when it is not showing, then you just call it with a boolean when you want it to appear, either in the logic, or with a button or link.

Comment: hey dude thanks for the elaborate answer!! ended up going with the first option...although the directive would be nice to implement later